# Jetty SslContextFactory: Print all allowed cipher suites

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I used a embedded jetty server with SslContextFactory. Does someone knows how I can print at server start all allowed cipher suites?

All I know yet is this:

```
String[] includedCipherSuites = sslContextFactory.getIncludeCipherSuites()
//print string array of included cipher suites
```

But this works just for all cipher suites I inserted before via:

```
sslContextFactory.setIncludeCipherSuites(this.includeCipherSuites);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once the `Server` is started, and the `SslContextFactory` has been started (via its lifecycle), then the [`SSLEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html) is used for the source of this information.

Note: the debug logging for `SslContextFactory` includes the list of enabled protocols and ciphers on startup.

Example (from Jetty 9.3.15+ and 9.4.0+) (Improvement [#1108](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1108)):

```java
SslContextFactory@1ed4004b(null,null) trustAll=false
 +- Protocol Selections
 |   +- Enabled (size=3)
 |   |   +- TLSv1
 |   |   +- TLSv1.1
 |   |   +- TLSv1.2
 |   +- Disabled (size=2)
 |       +- SSLv2Hello - ConfigExcluded:'SSLv2Hello'
 |       +- SSLv3 - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'SSLv3'
 +- Cipher Suite Selections
     +- Enabled (size=15)
     |   +- TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
     |   +- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     +- Disabled (size=42)
         +- SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5 - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - JreDisabled:java.security
         +- TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - JreDisabled:java.security
         +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5 - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5 - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5 - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256 - JreDisabled:java.security
```

Example (from Jetty 9.2.10):

```
2015-04-23 10:14:36.895:INFO::main: Logging initialized @133ms
2015-04-23 10:14:36.975:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.10.v20150310
2015-04-23 10:14:36.999:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2437c6dc{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2015-04-23 10:14:37.195:DBUG:oejus.SslContextFactory:main: Enabled Protocols [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2] of [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
2015-04-23 10:14:37.199:DBUG:oejus.SslContextFactory:main: Enabled Ciphers   [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV] of [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5]
2015-04-23 10:14:37.211:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@71423665{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9443}
2015-04-23 10:14:37.212:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @451ms
```

Otherwise, to do it in code.

```java
// once the server and ssl context factory are both started
SSLEngine engine = sslContextFactory.newSSLEngine();
String enabledProtocols[] = engine.getEnabledProtocols();
String supportedProtocols[] = engine.getSupportedProtocols();
String enabledCiphers[] = engine.getEnabledCipherSuites();
String supportedCiphers[] = engine.getSupportedCipherSuites();
```